# Reactive Redis only one thread is used in a webflux service

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

In a Webflux server, `detect` function first looks up 2 redis hash value, and then do a heavy CPU calculation using the redis returned value, and then save result to redis, and returns response. The idea is like this:

```
@PostMapping("detect")
public Mono<RecognitionResponse> detect(@Valid @RequestBody ImageVo vo) {
    float[] vec = ai.calculateVec(vo.getImg);
    Mono<Matrix> aLib= redisOps.get("aLib", "field").switchIfEmpty(...a default matrix...);
    Mono<Matrix> bLib = redisOps.get("bLib", "field").switchIfEmpty(...a default matrix...);
    return aLib.zipWith(bLib)
              .flatMap(tuple -> {
                     R r1 = ai.calculationSimilar(tuple.getT1(), vec);
                     R r2 = ai.calculationSimilar(tuple.getT2(), vec);
                     if (r1 or r2 newImage) {
                         return redisOps.put("aLib"， "field", r1.getVec()).map(b -> new RecognitionResponse(r1,r2))
                     } else {
                         return Mono.just(new RecognitionResponse(r1,r2));
                     }
               });
}
```

In a performance test, the above works fine given a 4 CPU server, like 380% is used. Given a 32 CPU server, very small part of CPU is used, `1` shows a `lettuce-epoll-thread` has a high CPU consumption like 90%. Then I checked `log`, it shows only one `lettuce-epoll-thread` is used for the whole `redisOps.get()` to `return` part, which is a heavy CPU calculation. (I printed for every ai function, and they all have the same `lettuce-epoll-thread number`)

I think first query redis, and then call a handler on returned data is an ordinary usage for webflux. If only one lettuce-epool thread is used, then performance would be very bad. I am starting to think that the above is a misuse of Webflux reactive redis.

**Supplement**
In a test, thread-level `top` shows that the thread that eats most CPU is thread 4807:

```
top - 11:33:00 up 486 days, 9 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.55, 1.62, 1.17
Threads: 326 total,  10 running, 316 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.2 us,  1.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 90.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13183149+total, 63810604 free, 35841708 used, 32179184 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 20971516 total, 20971516 free,        0 used. 89526880 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4807 tina  20   0 78.933g 0.013t  44980 R 95.7 11.0   8:13.02 java
14946 tina  20   0 78.933g 0.013t  44980 R  6.0 11.0   0:35.34 java
14733 tina  20   0 78.933g 0.013t  44980 S  5.3 11.0   0:28.25 java
```

And then 4807, equally 0x12c7, is `lettuce-epollEventLoop-5-12`::

```
"lettuce-epollEventLoop-5-12" #197 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9554002800 nid=0x12c7 runnable [0x00007f911a4ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:388)
        - locked <0x000000009b0a79d0> (a java.lang.StringBuffer)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.toString(ByteBuffer.java:1088)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:557)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at io.lettuce.core.output.CommandOutput.toString(CommandOutput.java:151)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.toString(CommandWrapper.java:219)
        at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.safeObjectAppend(MessageFormatter.java:277)
        at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.deeplyAppendParameter(MessageFormatter.java:249)
        at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:211)
        at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:161)
        at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(MessageFormatter.java:151)
        at io.netty.util.internal.logging.LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.debug(LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.java:115)
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.decode(RedisStateMachine.java:145)
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:742)
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode0(CommandHandler.java:706)
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:701)
```

`jvisualvm` results self time and thread cpu time, `io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.takeTask()` is the highest, and then comes `io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait`

**self time:**

[image: self time]

**thread cpu time:**

[image: thread cpu time]

Comment: what is heavy for your cpu redisOps.get() or the code inside flatmap?

Comment: logically  redisOps.get should not be high cpu usage for your service for redis maybe but not for you as you dont do calculations there all the find is done by redis in BG

Comment: as @Richard mentioned `redisOps.get` should not be CPU intensive and running on `parallel` scheduler that is using small number of threads. Not sure about `ai.calculationSimilar` but in case this is blocking, you need to scheduler it on a separate scheduler https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: @RicardKollcaku `ai.calculationSimilar` is AI operations written in another language, eats a lot of CPU, it is in `flatMap`. `redisOps.get` may not be heavy, although data amount could be very large (around 10 MB). I am not sure lettuce-eventloop thread is always on the same CPU core as AI operations. No matter whether or not, lettuce-eventloop thread is located on the same CPU core as AI operations, its CPU load is very high, like 90%.

Comment: @Alex I updated my post (the supplement part).